# how to show read only property in soap result in C#

Tags: c#, soap

I create a web service that return SOAP class object with one calculated property.
In debugging mode I see all fields with values, but the problem is the SOAP doesn't return the calculated property "Description"

this is the code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("User")]
    public Details SendSMS(string source, string destination,  string text)
    {   
        ..........
        return  Details;
    }

   public class Details
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }


    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription<ErrorCode((ErrorCode)ErrorCode);
        }
    } 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string OAddress { get; set; }
    public string DAddress { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It's near impossible to help solve your issue with just a few sentences of vague info (without making educated guesses).

Comment: code has been added

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with your reciving get; set 
check it line by line look like this for example:

```
{
        get
        {
            return EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription<ErrorCode((ErrorCode)ErrorCode);
        }
} 
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string OAddress { get; set; }
public string DAddress { get; set; }
```

Get enum for 3 and 4

Comment: Hi Elay. Welcome. Please read through [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to understand what's the best way to contribute to SO.